# OData Objective-C Client - Forms Based Authentication

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, forms-authentication, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a WCF data service hosted on a IIS server; I am using the Objective-C OData client implementation to query the WCF Data service.

I am now ready to deploy my service to a live server, and wish to provide an authentication mechanism, so that access to the service is restricted and also so I have an audit trail.

I have decided to use the ASP.NET Membership provider for this functionality. Users will register a username / password against a different (unprotected) service, which will enable them to access the restricted service.

I understand that I can use the `ObjectConext::OnBeforeSend` callback to setup the appropriate headers on the HTTP request, but I am unsure of how to do this. Would anyone have any examples?

EDIT

I do know how to add the headers to the request, this is not what I am asking. I am asking specifically, what headers do I actually add?

```
- (void) onBeforeSend: (HttpRequest*)request{
[request.m_httpHeaders.m_httpHeaders addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary
dictionaryWithObject:@"BlahBlahBlah" forKey:@"SomeHeader"]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know if it's too late for you but here is the working way:

```
- (void) onBeforeSend: (HttpRequest*)request{
     [request.m_httpHeaders.m_httpHeaders addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary
      dictionaryWithObject:@".ASPXAUTH=YourToken" forKey:@"Cookie"]];
 }
```

OR (depends on your iOS version i guess)

```
- (void) onBeforeHttpRequest: (HttpRequest*)request{
     [request.m_httpHeaders.m_httpHeaders addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary
      dictionaryWithObject:@".ASPXAUTH=YourToken" forKey:@"Cookie"]];
 }
```